# Character gains military traits despite not leading troops

Tags: crusader-kings-2

The current character I am playing has descent martial skills (8), but not enough to lead any troops. This is quite common for me, it is more often I let other characters with higher martial skills lead.

However, quite often I gain a military trait anyway, just now I chose to be an *inspring leader*.

My question is. Does this trait matter at all if the character doesn't lead any troops? Is the currently played character participating in the battles anyway?

Somehow it seems so, since I gained the trait, but I still suspect it doesn't matter unless I assign him as a leader.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are more leaders in an army than just the three main flank leaders. If you expand out the information panel on an army like this:

[image: Expanded army page]

You can see that every individual levy/retinue/mercenary unit has its own leader slot as well. If I recall correctly, whenever you raise your own personal levies, your character will assume control of that unit of soldiers, so may be "leading from the background" so to speak.

Edit: You can also always check to see if your character is leading troops by checking for a little sword icon on the top left of his portrait.

Also, the trait Inspiring Leader, like all army leadership traits, has no use outside of combat. You can find a full list of these traits and their bonuses here:[Military Leadership Traits](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Traits#Leadership)

Comment: Excellent! I recall seeing that but I never really payed any attention to it. Makes me glad, because my military traits are not worthless after all. :)

Comment: @Magnilex They are worthless unless you are the stack leader. However, it may be worth leading a stack even with a lowish martial. This is because high martial does almost nothing if there are no bonuses they can apply!